# UITableViewAutomaticDimension on custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for multiline `UILabel` in `UITableViewCell` and everything works fine on iPhone. To add a margin to the table view on iPad I'm using a custom subclass overriding `setFrame`:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (IS_IPAD) {
        CGFloat inset = 100;
        frame.origin.x += inset;
        frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

The problem is, that the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is returning the wrong (too small) height for the cell on iPad and the label gets cut off. I assume it's returning the height calculated for the full width.

Is there any way to get the table view calculate the right height?

**EDIT:**
found a quite hacky solution, but this does not work when setting attributedText

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (IS_IPAD) {
        CGFloat inset = 100;
        frame.origin.x += inset;
        frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;

        for (UIView *subview in self.contentView.subviews) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                UILabel *label = (UILabel *)subview;
                if (label.numberOfLines == 0) {
                    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = frame.size.width;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing something like this. Combining technology of **Size Classes** and **Auto-Layout** is able to solve the problem in a very easy way. Otherwise, it will require a lot of redrawing and calculation when you want to do that in a manual way. Also, when you are using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, you should go with this way as well because this flag simply indicates that iOS should calculate the cell height automatically via **Auto-Layout**.

Comment: I tried that approach first. The main challenge was to make the TableViewCell smaller on iPad for a nicer layout, but be able to scroll at the  left and right side of the cell and keep the cell selection only in the smaller frame. I could have made the backgroud transparent and added a smaller subview, but the approach I used seemed to be a lot more easy, especially  because I got about 30 different cells.

Comment: You can create a separate xib file for this cell for iPad version. And then load different xib file based on the device.